# Vim auto line-breaking not working as expected (update: problem with neocomplete)

Tags: arch-linux, vim, vimrc

I'm trying to configure `vim` so that the text breaks automatically at 80 characters. I know the way to do this is with

set textwidth=80

However, the lines don't automatically break when I typed past 80 characters. It waits until I hit `Enter`, then it applies the 80 character rule to what I've typed, and places my cursor on the line below all of the newly formatted text. So, I hit `Enter`, it reformats, then I have to go one line up to continue typing from where I was. I would like it so that the line breaks happen automatically while I'm typing. This was the case before I switched to arch-linux, but I lost my `.vimrc` and I can't tell if it's an issue with my new `.vimrc` or something else.

Here's my current .vimrc. http://pastebin.com/A4H9E0SA

Edit: Okay, so I decided to go through and replace chunks of my `.vimrc` until I found which part of the code caused this issue. It turns out that it's neocomplete that's causing this issue. I tried removing a bunch of the neocomplete settings (see the bottom of my `.vimrc`, starting at line 112) to see if any of those lines were causing the issue. It appears merely having neocomplete on is the cause of this issue.

Can anyone replicate this issue with neocomplete and/or have any ideas as to how to fix this without completely removing this plugin?

Comment: If you add `noremap pp p`[v`]gq$` to your `vimrc` then pressing `pp` should do what you want.

Comment: I'd rather not have to press any keys to make this happen, though. And I'm sure it's possible, given that it worked in my previous configuration a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Your update changes completely the question. Probably you should make a new question providing details on your new problem, and removing the "already understood" part.

Comment: Gotcha, will do. Would it be better to delete this question, then, or get rid of the added detail leave it up?

Comment: @grish, don't delete it, the question is good. (just focus in subject at a time).

Answer (score 0):

I use set wrap margin 1 in a 80 char terminal

```
:set textwidth=80
:set wm=1
```

And it words pretty well.

(when you want to switch off wrapping do `:set wm=0` )

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that, but I'd prefer it not to depend on the terminal width since the terminals I work in vary in size.

Comment: @grish see my edit (= use both textwith and wrapmargin)

Comment: Doesn't quite fix my problem, does this configuration work on your machine with the rest of my vimrc?

Comment: @grish Sorry typo: not textwith but `textwidth=80`! (edit)

Comment: Ha, no worries, I made that change when I tried the code.

Comment: @grish, on my machines it works fine. Please try it directly in your session ( :set textwidth=20 to see it clearly)

Comment: see the updated question, I (sort of) found the issue. It turns out I don't need to use `set wm=1` to get it to work, either.

Comment: yes: you dont need `:set wm=1` because you added `:set wrap linebreak` (they have a similar behavior).